# Extract the certificate from a signed jar

Tags: java, jarsigner

Given a Java jar file that has been signed with `jarsigner` (by someone else, so I don't have the original input files), how can I extract the certificate? `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs` doesn't show as much information as `openssl x509 -text` so I would like to get the certificate out and convert it to PEM or something else `openssl` can read. (Or do the equivalent of `openssl x509 -text` within the Java ecosystem, if there is such a thing).

Comment: I believe you can use the non-accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856739/how-to-use-openssl-to-validate-a-sf-rsa-signature-created-by-the-jarsigner  i.e. `unzip -p your.jar META-INF/*.RSA | openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -text -print_certs`.  Worked for me

Comment: @e.dan In my case, it was `*.EC` instead of `*.RSA` but yes, it worked! Knowing that it's PKCS#7 helps.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped